# Where should Couchbase Server Tools be installed?

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to get the add-on tool for Couchbase, cbimport, to work.

I have the install file, couchbase-server-tools_7.2.0-linux_x86_64.tar.gz

...but where to install it on a Mac? Not obvious to me. Cannot I find any documentation with the answer.

thanks in advance...

Comment: Based on the filename, I don't think that will work on Mac. Maybe get the macOS version? https://docs.couchbase.com/cloud/reference/command-line-tools.html#download-and-install-the-couchbase-command-line-tools

Answer (score 1):

Matthew Groves is correct -- the macOS version of the tools can be downloaded from that link in the documentation he provided.

Alternatively, if you already have Couchbase Server installed locally, on macOS the `cbimport` tool (and several other tools) are present inside `Couchbase Server.app`.

To see the included command-line tools:

```
ls /Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/
```

To run `cbimport`:

```
/Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/cbimport
```

If you prefer to refer to the command as simply `cbimport`, add that `bin` directory to your path:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this out soon...

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed, and cbimport is now working....